# Switch users in git

Tags: git

I have a following scenario:

We have environment with custom program that several people develop in - basically shared file system location and it's under Git control.

People change stuff in this location. I want to be able to switch users when they commit - what's the easiest way to do it?

Comment: `git config user.name` and `git config user.email`? This sounds like a terrible idea.

Answer (score 2):

As long as each person is logged in with their own separate account, make sure that each of them has a .gitconfig file in their home directory.

Add a [user] section and define the name and email:

```
[user]
name = John Smith
email = john@example.com
```

Comment: this looks like the best solution so far, let me try

Answer (score 1):

On each machine should have 1 User git, configured with the command `git config --global user.name = USER_NAME` and `git config --global user.email = USER_EMAIL`, Do you need to have multiple users on the same machine? If it, I think the easiest way is a script that requests User and email before commit, to run this commands before commit.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate branches for each person working on the project. I suppose you could think about it like usernames and then you can `git checkout <branchname>` (this switches between branches) then you will all have you own repos and be able to store you own commits.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the username of the person who makes the commit:

```
git commit --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"
```